# Even after passing updated value from parent to child, child is not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the parent component, I receive data from the server and then map this data into a jsx format. Inside this mapping I have a child component and try to pass a value from state of parent to child as a property, however when I update state of this value, the render function for child is not executed.

Expected behavior: As a user I see a list of items. If I click on an item it should become as checked.

```
export class ReactSample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      mappedItems: [],
      selectedIds: [],
      isSelected: false,
      clickedTripId: null
    };

    this.toggleSelection = this.toggleSelection.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    console.log("Component mounting")
  }

  toggleSelection (id, e) {
    if(!_.includes(this.state.selectedIds, id)) {
      this.setState((state) => ({selectedIds: 
state.selectedIds.concat(id)}));
      this.setState(() => ({clickedTripId: id}));
      this.mapItems(this.state.items);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;
    MyService.getItems()
      .then(res => {
        self.setState(() => ({ items: res.allItems }));
        self.setState(() => ({ mappedItems: 
this.mapItems(res.allItems) }));
      }
    )
  }

  mapItems (items) {
return items.map(trip => {
  return (
    <li key={trip.id} onClick={(e) => (this.toggleSelection(trip.id, 
e))}>
      <span>{trip.title}</span>
      <Tick ticked={this.state.clickedTripId}/>
      <span className="close-item"></span>
    </li>
  );
});
  }

  getItems() {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a className="title">This is a react component!</a>
        <Spinner showSpinner={this.state.items.length <= 0}/>
        <div className="items-container">
          <ul id="itemsList">
            {this.state.mappedItems}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export class Tick extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('RENDER');
    return (<span className={this.props.ticked ? 'tick display' : 
'tick hide' }></span>);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ryan already said, the problem was that `mappedItems` where not updated when `toggleSelection` was clicked. As it is obvious from the code `mapItems` returns data in jsx format. To update it I had to call `this.setState({mappedItems: this.mapItems(this.state.items)})` which means that I call `mapItems` and then I assign the result to the state. In this case my list will be updated and `Tick` component will receive `this.state.clickedItemId` as a `tick` property. There is one more issue that needs to be done to make this code working: 
this mapped list needs to be updated after `this.state.clickedItemId` is updated. The method `setState` is asynchronous which means that `this.setState({mappedItems: this.mapItems(this.state.items)})` has to be called only after `this.state.clickedItemId` is updated. To achieve this, the `setState` method can receive a callback function as a second parameter. The code snippet is the following:

```
toggleSelection (id, e) {
  if(!_.includes(this.state.selectedIds, id)) {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      clickedItemId: id,
      selectedIds: state.selectedIds.concat(id)
    }), () => this.setState({mappedItems: this.mapItems(this.state.items)}));
  }
}
```

In this case, at the time the  `mapItems` function is executed all data from the state that is needed here will be already updated:

```
mapItems (items) {
  return items.map(item => {
    return (
      <li key={item.id} onClick={(e) => (this.toggleSelection(item.id, e))}>
        <span>{item.title}</span>
        <span>{this.state.clickedItemId}</span>
        <Tick ticked={this.state.clickedItemId === item.id}/>
        <span className="close-item"></span>
      </li>
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple issues.

In `toggleSelection` you aren't doing anything with the result of mapItems. This kind of bug would be much easier to avoid if you just remove `mappedItems` from state and instead just call `mapItems` within your render method.

The other issue is you are passing `this.state.clickedTripId` as the `ticked` property. I assume you meant to pass something more like `this.state.clickedTripId === trip.id`.

Comment: Thank you Ryan for your replay. Initially, I had done mapping in the render function but then I read from official documentation that `render` function should be kept as a cleaner as it is possible. That is why I moved "mappings" into another place. But you are right that I do nothing with mapped items. My map class function returns a result and I had to call `setState` on calling map function inside my `toggleSelection` function in order to update `mappedItems`!